# LINQ Changes Not Recognized When Using Generics

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, generics, partial-classes

I am currently trying to create a Class which employs generics in order to reduce the amount of work needed for future development.  As I add Tables to the LINQ To SQL Designer, certain basic Methods are used in each one.  Rather than reproduce them in every Partial Class associated with every new Table, I would like to employ a single generic Class.  The issue is that any changes made to the Entities are not recognized and therefore not submitted.

```
Public Partial Class ABC
{
  Public Static Bool Synchronize(string source, string destination)
  {
    try
    {
      DataContext destinationDB = DataConnection.Destination(destination);
      Table<ABC> destinationABCs = destinationDB.ABCs;

      DataContext sourceDB = DataConnection.Destination(source)
      Table<ABC> sourceABCs = sourceDB.ABCs;

      foreach (ABC ABCCode in sourceABCs)
      {
        ABC destABCCode = destinationABCs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == ABCCode.Id);

        bool same = EntityProcessing.AreIdentical(ABCCode, destABCCode);

        if (same == false)
        {
          destABCCode = (ABC)EntityProcessing.Synchronize(ABCCode, destABCCode);
        }
      }
      ChangeSet test = destinationDB.GetChangeSet();  // Test Line For Debugging
      destinationDB.SubmitChanges();
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

The next Class is:

```
Public Static Class EntityProcessing
{
  Public Static Bool AreIdentical(Object sourceEntity, Object destinationEntity)
  {
     if (sourceEntity.GetType() == destinationEntity.GetType())
     {
       Type t = sourceEntity.GetType();
       FieldInfo[] tList = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

       foreach (FieldInfo fi in tList)
       {
         if ((fi.GetValue(sourceEntity) != null ? fi.GetValue(sourceEntity).ToString()
            : null) == (fi.GetValue(destinationEntity) != null ?
            fi.GetValue(destinationEntity).ToString() : null))
         { continue; }
         else
         { return false; }
       }
       return true;
     }
     else
     { return false; }
  }

  Public Static Object Synchronize(Object sourceEntity, Object destinationEntity)
  {
    if (sourceEntity.GetType() == destinationEntity.GetType())
    {
      Type t = sourceEntity.GetType();
      FieldInfo[] tList = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

      foreach (FieldInfo fi in tList)
      {
        fi.SetValue(destinationEntity, fi.GetValue(sourceEntity));
      }
    }
    return destinationEntity;
  }
}
```

I have tried modifying the `EntityProcessing.Synchronize` method into a Void method as well.  Neither works.  Both will return the correct Entity with the Fields set to the appropriate results.  The issue lies in the fact that LINQ does not recognize the Entities as having changed.

If I add a temporary line of `ChangeSet test = destinationDB.GetChangeSet();`, the Updated count is zero.  The loss appears to be in the conversion to Objects.

I have tried setting the Parameter Type to `ABC` on the `EntityProcessing.Synchronize()` method and modifying a Field, and the Updated count in `test` is correct.  How do I resolve this?

**How do I submit the updated entities to the database or rather, how do I get LINQ to recognize these entities are being changed and needing an update?**

Comment: What happens in the body of `EntityProcessing.Synchronize()` ?

Comment: I don't see generics here.  Where are they?

Comment: @Mark Cidade, @David B, Generic Methods have been added. Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean: `Public Static Bool Synchronize<ABC>(string source, string destination)` with "ABC" as the generic type?

However, I don't think your `.ABCs` will work that simply.  You may have to use reflection to get at the proeprty with that particular name.  For example, first use reflection to get the name of the type parameter (ABC), and then use reflection to get the table field from the data source based on this type name.

Comment: I have added the Methods to the EntityProcessing Class.  That might help you understand my intent a bit better.  Thank you for any assistance.